# Gerar classes com XSD ou importar WSDL [ANS / TISS]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, xsd

A *ANS* fornece os arquivos `.XSD`, e os `.WSDL` para implementação do protocolo *TISS*.

**S**e eu gero o código pelo .XSD, tenho as classes estruturadas de forma correta. Exemplo:

```
namespace TissV3
{
    class Cabecalho
    {
       ...
    }

    class MensagemA
    {
       public Cabecalho cabecalhoTransacao {get;set;}
    }

    class MensagemB
    {
       public Cabecalho cabecalhoTransacao {get;set;}
    }
}
```

De forma que, o cabeçalho da mensagem A, é do mesmo tipo do cabeçalho da mensagem B.

**M**as, se eu importar os WSDL para consumir os serviços, é gerado da seguinte forma:

```
namespace MensagemAv3
{
    class Cabecalho
    {
       ...
    }

    class MensagemA
    {
       public Cabecalho cabecalhoTransacao {get;set;}
    }

    class ClientSoap
    {
        ExecutarSolicitacao(MensagemA obj);
    }
}

namespace MensagemBv3
{
    class Cabecalho
    {
       ...
    }

    class MensagemB
    {
       public Cabecalho cabecalhoTransacao {get;set;}
    }

    class ClientSoap
    {
        ExecutarSolicitacao(MensagemB obj);
    }
}
```

De forma que, é gerado um objeto `Cabecalho` para cada mensagem (assim como muitos outros que compõem a mensagem). Nesse caso, não é possível reutilizar os códigos, eu teria que gerar cada cabecalho de cada mensagem... E também não é possível usar os objetos das classes geradas pelo XSD.

A questão é:

1. **Estou utilizando os schemas de forma correta?** *(e terei que alterar o
   código na mão, ou deixá-lo com esse monte de classes duplicadas...)*
2. **Há outras formas de implementar essas integrações quando é fornecido
   xsd/wsdl?**
3. **É possível que o problema seja na estrutura desenvolvida, neste
   caso, pela ANS ?**

---

> obs. Para gerar as classes pelo schema, utilizo o xsd.exe. Ainda assim tenho problemas pois algumas propriedades deveriam ser suprimidas se nulas e não são, então o xml gerado com essas classes não é validado pelo próprio schema que originou as classes. Esse problema vou acertando criando propriedades:

```
public bool [foo]Specified 
{
    get 
    { 
        return [foo] != null; 
    } 
    set { return; } 
}
```

Toda a [documentação fornecida pela ANS](http://www.ans.gov.br/prestadores/tiss-troca-de-informacao-de-saude-suplementar/padrao-tiss-dezembro-2017)

[Arquivo com os XSD e WSDL](http://www.ans.gov.br/images/stories/Plano_de_saude_e_Operadoras/tiss/Padrao_tiss/tiss3/Padrao_TISS_Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20030303.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Rovann, para facilitar em utilizações futura, criei um [Web App no GitHub](https://github.com/avmesquita/AspNetWebAppAnsTiss) já com os arquivos WSDL importados no aplicativo, pronto para utilização.

Todos querem o peixe, mas poucos ensinam a pescar. Segue o passo-a-passo da pescaria.

Para incorporar os arquivos WSDL, você precisa clicar com o botão direito sobre a solução e selecionar Add -> Service Reference, conforme:

[image: Passo 1]

Para importar os arquivos WSDL do TISS, você vai precisar acessar as opções avançadas, conforme:

[image: Passo 2]

Repetir os passos 1 e 2 até que todos os arquivos WSDL tenham sido incorporados à aplicação.

[image: Configurado]

Espero que ajude.